# UIScrollView's contentOffset being reset after viewDidLayoutSubviews

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I override `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and set the `contentOffset` of my `UIScrollview`. But the `contentOffset` always reset to (0, 0) before `viewDidAppear`. I print the `contentOffset` in `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, `viewDidAppear`. Here are the results.

```
view will appear
(0.0, 0.0)
view did layout subviews
(-37.5, -133.5)
view did appear
(0.0, 0.0)
```

I want to set the `contentOffset` before the `UIScrollView` become visible.

I tried `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false`, but not work.

Answer (score 0):

Because viewDidLayoutSubviews will call every child did layout. So, maybe your scrollview didn't layout at this time you set it.

Let try this. Hope it can help you. :)

```
let indexSubView = 0
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    indexSubView += 1
    if indexSubView >= self.view.subviews.count {
      //do scrolling
    }
}
```